# How can I get calculate for a git repo on OS X

Tags: macos, git, xcode4, code-statistics

I tried using gitstats (http://gitstats.sourceforge.net/), but the damn thing doesn't generate graphs.

It requires gnuplot, which requires a bunch of other libs to be installed, none of which have a native OS X port.  I've spent 4 hours trying to figure out how to install libpng to install libgd, to install lib... forget it.

Anyone know of a simpler way of generating visual git stat report for OS X?

Comment: Try homebrew for installing gnuplot http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/

Comment: @Felix, will that also install the png terminal support?  That's the main problem.

Comment: Good question, I don't know... let me try (but I can already say that homebrew also makes it easier to install third party libs).

Comment: It seemed to work for me, I was able to generate the HTML files.

Comment: @Felix, it always generates the HTML files.  But not the graphs.

Comment: There are also graphs... ;) I'm not sure whether libpng is a dependency though... I think I installed it separately some time ago (with homebrew of course).

Comment: @Felix, nope.  Fails to install gnuplot.  Failed executing: ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/pango/1.28.4 --with-x

Answer (score 4):

```
# homebrew rocks
brew install gnuplot

# 'install' gitstats
git clone git://repo.or.cz/gitstats.git

# create and open reports
./gitstats path_to_your_git_repo path_to_report_output
open path_to_report_output/index.html
```